# Install `mpl_toolkit.basemap` on RedHat without compiling from source

Tags: rhel, python

I need to install `matplotlib` and `mpl_toolkit.basemap` on a RedHat machine. `matplotlib` is already installed but for `mpl_toolkit.basemap` the only way I could find was to download the source and compile it and then running `python setup.py install` from terminal.

The trouble is the aforementioned server is remote and the disk quota is very limited that I can't download and install `mpl_toolkit.basemap`. Is there any prepared package I could install? If so, would you please provide the actual command to install it? I don't seem to find any.